# Is there a way to know the number of characters in a string?

Tags: javascript, string, utf-16

This question concerns unicode characters that are more than one utf-16 character

string.length returns the number of unicode 16 chars in the string. But what about the case of characters that are more than 1 unicode 16 character? Is it possible to get the actual number of characters as well as "true" values from string.charAt of the actual character, and not the utf-16 pieces?

```js
var test = "";
console.log(test.length)
var regex = /[\u{1F000}-\u{1F0FF}]/g;
var regex2 = //g
console.log('test: ' + regex.test(test));
console.log('test2: ' + regex2.test(test));
```

Comment: "unicode 16" do you mean UTF-16?

Comment: @phuzi Yes that is what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use spread operator:

```js
var test = "";
var test2 = [...test];
console.log(test.length);
console.log(test2.length);
```

about your second question, you need to modify regexp:

```js
var test = "";
console.log(test.length)
var regex = /[\u{1F000}-\u{1F0FF}]/ug;
var regex2 = //g
console.log('test: ' + regex.test(test));
console.log('test2: ' + regex2.test(test));
```

Comment: nice! Any way to get the character or run regexes where it is either part of the string or part of the text?

Comment: @ControlAltDel I don't understand your question

Comment: See my updated question. In one regex I am trying to match all characters between 1F000 an 1F0FF. This fails, as it seems \u functionality is not set to work in cases like this. the second regex works though

Comment: @ControlAltDel don't you forget to use `[]` to match range?

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: @ControlAltDel you also forgot `{}` around unicode codes

Comment: It's just odd to me that these characters that are beyond the range of \uFFFF need special treatment

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me through this! From your advice here, I found this page (https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode) which answers all the questions I have on this... I mean, you have too, but the page goes through it better, in part because of my limited understanding when I wrote the question and in part because of the way StackOverflow questions and answers are set up

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use RegExp with the unicode flag.

```js
var test = "";
var length = test.match(/./ug).length;
console.log(length);
```

Please note that this and the answer using the spread operator can break under certain circumstances.

```js
var test = "Z͑ͫ̓ͪ̂ͫ̽͏̴̙̤̞͉͚̯̞̠͍A̴̵̜̰͔ͫ͗͢L̠ͨͧͩ͘G̴̻͈͍͔̹̑͗̎̅͛́Ǫ̵̹̻̝̳͂̌̌͘";
var length = test.match(/./ug).length;
console.log(length);
```

To get the char at a specific index you can use the following function.

```js
var test = "";

var charAt = charAt(test);

console.log(charAt);

function charAt(string, index) {
    if(!index)
        index = 0;

    return string.match(/./ug)[index];
}
```